# How to export function inside of react functional component to be called in js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, import, export

I want to show a counter of how many comparisons my sorting algorithm is making (which is in a vanilla js file) by calling a function (or by simply changing the useState value directly) that is in my react file. I have been trying a few things but none are working, either I run into the problem of not being able to export a function that is in my react functional component or the counter will simply not show the update count (I would like for the count to be updated in real time. Anyone know a simple solution? I have found a potential solution but it seems to be too complicated for what seems to what could potentially have a simple solution

my vanilla js File:

```
export async function bubbleSort(arr){
    let swapped = false;
    for(var i = 0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
        swapped = false
        
        for(var j = 0;j<arr.length-1-i;j++){
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){ 
                document.getElementById(j).style.backgroundColor = "green"
                document.getElementById(j+1).style.backgroundColor = "red"
                //**********************************
                //Add update counter Here
                //***********************************
                await delay(50);
                swap(j, j +1)
                let temp = arr[j]
                arr[j]=arr[j +1];
                arr[j +1] = temp;
                swapped = true
            }else{
                document.getElementById(j).style.backgroundColor = "green";
                document.getElementById(j +1).style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
                await delay(50)
            }
            
            document.getElementById(j).style.backgroundColor = "";
            document.getElementById(j +1).style.backgroundColor = "green";
            
        } 
        if(!swapped){
            for(let k = 0;k<=i;k++){
                document.getElementById(k).style.backgroundColor = "green";
                await delay(30)
            }
            break
        }
        if(j == 0 && i == arr.length-2)document.getElementById(j).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

my react file:

```
// export function callUpdateBubble(){
//   updateBubbleCount();
// }
function SortingPage(){
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);

  //This counter ********************************
  const [bubbleCount, setBubbleCount] = useState(0)
  //*********************************************

//This function ********************************
  function updateBubbleCount(){
    setBubbleCount(bubbleCount+ 1)
  }
//*********************************************

  let idx = 0;
  useEffect(() => {
    resetArray()
  }, []);
  function resetArray(length) {
    const arr = [];
    let i
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (350-5) + 5));
    }
    
    setLines(arr);
  }
  function getWidth(){
    let x = lines.length;
    if(x<10){
        return 30;
    }else if(x<30){
        return 20;
    }else if(x<40){
        return 10;
    }else if(x<60){
        return 5;
    }else{
        return 3;
    }
    
  }
  function deletes(){
    let length = lines.length-1;
    setLines(lines.filter(line => line !== lines[length]))
    
  }
  function bubble(){
    bubbleSort(lines)
  }
  
    return (
      <>
        <header className="header">
          <a className="logo" onClick={() => navigate("/")}>
            Algorithms Visualizer
          </a>
          <nav className="navbar">
            <a onClick={() => navigate("/sorting")}>Sorting Algorithms</a>
            <a onClick={() => navigate("/pathfinding")}>
              Pathfinding Algorithms
            </a>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <div className="container">
          {lines.length > 0 &&
            lines.map((line, idx) => (
              <div
                key={idx}
                id={idx++}
                className="line"
                style={{
                  height: `${line * 1.3 + 30}px`,
                  padding: `0px ${getWidth()}px`,
                  backgroundColor: ""
                }}
              ></div>
            ))}

          <button className="bubble" onClick={bubble}>
            Bubble Sort
          </button>
          <div className="count" style={{paddingLeft: "20px"}}>{bubbleCount}</div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  

  
}

export default SortingPage;
```

I have tried exporting functions that will update the useState, I have also tried passing the useState variables as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going the functional way, keep your function the purest you can, here, just pass the function as an optionnal callback parameter:

```
    export async function bubbleSort(arr, optionnal_counter_callback){
    let swapped = false;
    for(var i = 0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
        swapped = false
        
        for(var j = 0;j<arr.length-1-i;j++){
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){ 
                document.getElementById(j).style.backgroundColor = "green"
                document.getElementById(j+1).style.backgroundColor = "red"
                //**********************************
                //Add update counter Here
                //***********************************
                if (optionnal_counter_callback) optionnal_counter_callback();
                await delay(50);
                swap(j, j +1)
                let temp = arr[j]
                arr[j]=arr[j +1];
                arr[j +1] = temp;
                swapped = true
            }else{
                document.getElementById(j).style.backgroundColor = "green";
                document.getElementById(j +1).style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
                await delay(50)
            }
            
            document.getElementById(j).style.backgroundColor = "";
            document.getElementById(j +1).style.backgroundColor = "green";
            
        } 
        if(!swapped){
            for(let k = 0;k<=i;k++){
                document.getElementById(k).style.backgroundColor = "green";
                await delay(30)
            }
            break
        }
        if(j == 0 && i == arr.length-2)document.getElementById(j).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

secondly, updateBubbleCount has to be changed to keep it purest as you can again (no external dependency tu bubbleCount):

```
function updateBubbleCount(){
    setBubbleCount(function (c) { return c + 1;})
}
```

finally the bullbe function need an update too:

```
function bubble(){
    bubbleSort(lines, updateBubbleCount);
}
```

I didn't try it but it should make the do